# Handling array in sql query for php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Attempting to create a sql query which takes in an array of tags (3 maximum) and then displays the records which match any of those tags.

so far I have this:

```
<?php

  include "db_conx.php";

  if 
    (!isset ($_POST['tag']))
  {
    $message = 'Please select valid tags';

  }

  try {

    $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    $sql = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, c.course_title, pt.*, t.tag_title  FROM proposal p 
      LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
      LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code
  WHERE pt.tag_code IN ('.implode(',', '$tag').')');

    $sql->bindParam(':tag', $course, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sql->execute();
    $count = $sql->rowCount();
    //$user_record_id = $sql->fetchColumn();

    $prop_tags = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $course_title = $sql->fetchColumn(3);


    if( ! $proposals)
{
    die('<h4><center><p class=text-danger>There are no proposals available for this course</p></center></h4>');



}
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
  }
  ?>

  <?php
echo "<h2>Tags Chosen:</h2>";

var_dump($tag);
?>
```

and this is the code for the form which gets processed:

```
 <?php

  include "db_conx.php";

  try
  {

  $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM tag_details ORDER BY tag_title ASC');
    $stmt->execute();
    //$count = $stmt>rowCount();
    $tags = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
  $e->getMessage();
    }


?>


    <div id="adSearchModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="adSearchModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Advanced Search </h4>
            <p class="text-danger"><small>(Select up to 3)</small></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="adsearchForm" action="Student_AdSearch.php" method="post">

              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="tag_details">Select Tags:</label><p></p>
                <div class="checkbox-new">
                  <?php foreach($tags as $tag): ?>

                  <input name='tag[]' class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $tag['tag_code'] ?>"><?php echo $tag['tag_title'] ?></p>

                <?php endforeach ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION['user_token'];  ?>"/>

            <div class="modal-footer">

              <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
                <input type="Submit" class= "btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea how i can achieve my end goal?

In essence the query should return all the proposals which match those tags. I have tested the sql query by manually giving it 3 tags and that works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? Enable error reporting and catch PDO errors, then try to solve them. From the looks simple backticks could solve this (if your tags are strings), making `.. IN (foo,bar)` `.. IN ('foo','bar')`

Comment: for some reason it doesn't like the ';'. i keep running into this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/insights/Student_AdSearch.php on line 118 which happens to be the same line as the WHERE clause

Comment: You are missing a `)` (from the prepare method). Also the quotes around the implode stuff are wrong (`"` need to be `'`)

Comment: Thanks for that @kingkero i've sorted the brackets and the ' however now I'm getting an error which says implode has invalid arguments. i have updated the code above with the changes

Comment: Think I've found the issue. It was the ' ' i used. since I'm not returning a string i didn't need them. :)

Comment: I edit my answer see it

Answer (score 0):

In your code change your $sql to:

```
$sql = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, c.course_title, pt.*, t.tag_title  FROM proposal p 
  LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
  LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
  LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code
  WHERE pt.tag_code IN (' . implode(',', $tag) .')';

    $prop_tags = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $course_title = $sql->fetchColumn(3);

/*
add this lines
*/
foreach($prop_tags as $info) {
echo implode(' - ', $info) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: No doesn't work. I keep getting an error. See above comment. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, i have managed to make it work without those extra lines of code. Those extra lines would print exactly whats held in those value however i will be using a table to display this information. Thanks again

Comment: It didn't sorry. those extra lines of code were of no use to me. thanks anyway